# WP table data displays differently on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, html-table

I have a table on my site:

```
    <table>
<tbody>

<tr>
<td>
<p style="text-align: center;">
some text
some text
some text
</p>
p style="text-align: center;">
<strong><span style="font-family: Arial;">SOME BOLD TEXT</span></strong></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
some text
some text
some text
</p>
</td><p style="text-align: center;">
some text
some text
some text
</p>
p style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="font-family: Arial;">SOME BOLD TEXT</span></strong></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
some text
some text
some text
</p>
<td><p style="text-align: center;">
some text
some text
some text
</p>
p style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="font-family: Arial;">SOME BOLD TEXT</span></strong></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
some text
some text
some text
</p>
</td><p style="text-align: center;">
some text
some text
some text
</p>
p style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="font-family: Arial;">SOME BOLD TEXT</span></strong></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
some text
some text
some text
</p>
</tr>
</tr>
<td><p style="text-align: center;">
some text
some text
some text
</p>
p style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="font-family: Arial;">SOME BOLD TEXT</span></strong></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
some text
some text
some text
</p>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</tbody>
```

For some reason when viewing on a mobile, the FIRST TD is displayed differently => background is gray (I was able to get rid of it adding `style="background-color: #ffffff;"` to the first `TD <>`. 
The main problem I have, is that ALL text is shown BOLD.
Any idea how I can change this please or why it is doing it?
The website is:
http://www.aguaris.com/en/references-mallorca-hotels/
And it is doing the same thing with all tables on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an inline css somewhere that looks like this, and accounts for the grey colour and the bold:

```
tr td:first-child {background: #f0f0f0; font-weight:bold;font-size:1.3em;}
```

As you say, it's only coming into play on mobile. That's because it's enclosed in

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { ...}
```

If you look at the source you will see at the code between 99 and 171, with the offending section between 116 and 128 . The code starts with some German comments.

If you can't track down the file and create an override for it somehow, you might find that putting this in your style.css (or custom.css if you aren't using a child theme) will do the job:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
tr td:first-child {background: #ffffff!important; font-weight:400!important;}
}
```

Better to try and deal with it properly though I think, through an override given that you want to correct it for all tables on the site, not just the one.

With the German comments there, it should be easy enough to track down the file by searching the code in the site?

Comment: THANK YOU!! Since I was not able to find the code with the comments, I added your code in the style file and it worked!! ;)

Comment: Great - glad that sorted it and thanks for letting me know. :D